# Need to convert Spark to Python to copy DF to Azure SQL Server

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Scala code which works fine in a Spark environment, but we just switched over to Python last week.  I need to convert the code to run in a Python setup.  How can I do that?

```
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.bulkcopy.BulkCopyMetadata
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

val bulkCopyConfig = Config(Map(
  "url"               -> "mysqlserver.database.windows.net",
  "databaseName"      -> "MyDatabase",
  "user"              -> "username",
  "password"          -> "*********",
  "databaseName"      -> "MyDatabase",
  "dbTable"           -> "dbo.Clients",
  "bulkCopyBatchSize" -> "2500",
  "bulkCopyTableLock" -> "true",
  "bulkCopyTimeout"   -> "600"
))

df.bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkCopyConfig)
```

Code comes from here.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark/blob/master/README.md

It seems like the code should be essentially the same, but I'm sure some of the formatting will be different.

I am also looking at the site below, but I'm not seeing anything super-useful.

http://www.nerdsgene.com/Article/BulkCopyToSQLDB

Any thought?  Thanks to all!